# Ruby - Trying to create an unbeatable game

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a version of the game I created where the program(computer) always wins. Game is Rock Paper Scissors.

I am a beginner in Ruby, I have successfully created the "normal" version of the game where the coputer chooses its results at random.  I have been searching for awhile and stuck for about a day on this simple problem.

If anyone can point me in the write direction, as I do not really want the solution solved for me as I am really trying to learn this.  But I feel I am missing something important.  I had the idea of using the Minimax algorithm so I just started reading into that as well.

I am very open to different solutions to this problem.

Below is my current "Normal" version of the game. And also the part I believe the change needs to take place... where the computer makes it selection based on the users input. Then I will show the section I was trying to make in the same game, but having the computer always win.

Question: How do I have the computer makes its selection correctly based on user input?  I know many options exit in Ruby, I am open to different solutions or types of solution that I can incorporate into my program.

Thank you for any/all responses in advance.

```
 def get_player_play
   prompt 
   @player_play = gets.chomp.upcase.to_sym 
   @winner = :invalid if  @player_play != :R || :P || :S  
   @winner = :score if @player_play == :X
   @winner = "" if @player_play == :Q
 end

 def get_computer_play
   @computer_play = WINS.keys.sample
 end

 def get_winner
  if @player_play == @computer_play then @winner = nil
  else
  @winner = :player   if WINS[@player_play] == @computer_play 
  @winner = :computer if WINS[@computer_play] == @player_play  
  end
 end
```

Here is what I have tried (plus many variations of the same type of if/else statements).

```
 #this makes it a tie
    def get_computer_play 
        if NAME[@player_play] == ( NAME[:R] )
         return @computer_play = WIN[:P]
       elsif NAME[@player_play] == ( NAME[:P] )
         return @computer_play = WIN[:S]
       else 
         NAME[@player_play] == ( NAME[:S] )
         return @computer_play = WIN[:R]
       end
    end
```

Comment: You're going to need to trim this down a lot more before we can help you. This isn't a technical problem so much as a dump of code.

Comment: To avoid confusing yourself, please pay very careful attention to indentation and try to avoid one-lining things for no reason. Ruby allows a lot of short-hand that's technically valid but hard to read. `if ... then ... end` on one line is one such example. Spread that out so the branching is clear.

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick responses.  Trimming down the code for starters now...

Comment: This code is pretty confused, though I'll say that's normal for someone just getting started. What you'll want to do is try and create methods with a singular, express purpose, and give those methods names that communicate their intent and function. `get_computer_play` doesn't take any input, it just uses state information that happens to be kicking around, and it does so in a way that's far from clear. A better approach is `computer_play_for(move)` where that's self-contained.

Comment: i don't know tic tac toe in that much detail, is it even possible for the computer to win under _every circumstance_ as you request?

Comment: @maxpleaner This is rock-paper-scissors, not tic-tac-toe. (And for the record, it's possible to at least force a draw in any game of tic-tac-toe.)

Comment: @tadman Thank you.  This is my first attempt at a Ruby program, your suggestion makes sense. Will work at that now.

Comment: Another thing to note is `@player_play != :R || :P || :S` does not do what you think it does, it's equivalent to `(@player_play != :R) || :P || :S`. The `||=` gets evaluated first, and `:P || :S` never evaluated because that's the first non logically false value has been found. You probably mean `![:R, :P, :S].include?(@player_play)` where that array should end up a constant if you use it frequently. This is because of [operator precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

Comment: Is this possible without the computer cheating?

Comment: @SagarPandya That is my goal :) I want one version of the game... normal where the computer chooses turns at random.  That I did, and it works!   The second version the goal is to make the computer cheat based on the users input.

Comment: I understand that you don't want answers that show how your code can be fixed. Do you want answers that are complete solutions but take a different approach (@SagarPandya's answer, for example)? I think it would be to your advantage to see more Ruby-like ways to approach the problem. In any event, please edit to clarify that point.

Comment: @caryswoveland. Thanks for your message.  I will edit the message within a few hours when I get back from our health appointment for new family member in the works!    Yes I would appreciate another approach....   I just got a book in the mail-  object oriented ruby and I am going over that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different, more Ruby-like, approach.

```
WINNERS = { "rock"=>"paper", "scissors"=>"rock", "paper"=>"scissors" }

def cheat
  loop do
    puts "rock, paper or scissors?"
    computer = WINNERS[gets.downcase.chomp]
    if computer
      puts "You lose, computer chose #{computer}."
      break
    end
    puts "That entry is invalid. Try again."
  end
end

cheat #=> (enter "rock")     "You lose, computer chooses paper."
cheat #=> (enter "papter")   "That entry is invalid. Try again."
cheat #=> (enter "paper")    "You lose, computer chooses scissors."
cheat #=> (enter "scissors") "You lose, computer chooses rock."
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a rigged game, use a [case-expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) along the lines of:

```
puts "Rock, paper or scissors?"
ans = gets.downcase.chomp

case ans
when "rock"
  puts "You lose, computer chose paper"
when "paper"
  #insert code here
when "scissors"
  #insert code here
end
```